# Default FirebaseApp is no initialized in process (Error)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a firebase app, where i have to just save content to the real-time database in firebase. i got an error in the logcat says

"*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.myfirebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.*"

Even after initializing the FirebaseApp, my app is getting crash. Please help me out.

```
package com.example.myfirebase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText name,email;
    private Button save;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AddData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void AddData(){
        String Name = name.getText().toString().trim();
        String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();

        SaveData saveData = new SaveData(Name,Email);

        databaseReference.setValue(saveData);
    }

}
```

I want to save content to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your project level gradle file class path of firebase :-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: leave a comment if you have any query or appricate the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

Add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` in your application class not in `Activity`.

Create class extends `Application`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }
}
```

In Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are working on a device without Google Play services, or didn't add com.google.gms:google-services to your project?

[This page](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) seems to indicate you get that error for Flutter apps if you leave out Google Play Services, so it could be the same for you.